# Changing the font size of rotatebox

Tags: formatting, rotating, text-manipulation

How can we change the font size of the text appearing in the rotatebox? 
For example:

```
\rotatebox{90}{test text}
```

I would like to change the size of "test text".

Comment: `\large test text` ? The font size is totally unrelated to the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\rotatebox{90}{\large test text}
```

Or any other LaTeX command inside the box. The font size is totally unrelated to the rotation.